# [Groovy Beta] Troubles migrating to catkin

Tags: ros, catkin, groovy-beta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed the groovy base packages following these [instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source). I want to convert my packages (I wrote) to catkin so they are "groovy". However, when I run `catkin_make`, nothing gets built.

I converted my manifest.xml to a package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>serial_node</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>serial_node</description>

  <maintainer email="kevin@todo.todo">kevin</maintainer>


  <license>BSD</license>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- You can specify that this package is a metapackage here: -->
    <!-- <metapackage/> -->
    
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->

  </export>
</package>
```

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(serial_node)

## Find catkin and system dependencies

## Find catkin and any catkin packages on which
## this package depends at build time
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)

## Declare ROS messages and services

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
   DIRECTORY srv
   FILES
   serial.srv
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare things to be passed to other projects
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs # catkin-pkg1 catkin-pkg2
#  DEPENDS Boost # other-3rd-party-libraries
)

## Specify additional locations of header files
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})


## Declare a cpp executable
add_executable(serial_node src/serial_node_service.cpp)
```

I have sourced setup.bash and my environment is:

```
[kevin@tardis serial_node]$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/src:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_TEST_RESULTS_DIR=/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build/test_results
ROS_OS_OVERRIDE=osx:homebrew
ROS_NO_SUDO_PIP=True
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/roslib
```

In the package directory, when I run `catkin_make` I don't get any binaries in the devel or build folder.

```
[kevin@tardis serial_node]$ catkin_make
Base path: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node
Source space: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/src
Build space: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build
Devel space: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/devel
Install space: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/install" in "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build"
####
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 4.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/groovy
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/groovy
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.2") 
-- Found PY_em: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/em.pyc  
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.52
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j2" in "/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build"
####
[kevin@tardis serial_node]$
```

---

**Update [3 Dec 12]**

The files in my package are:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   2.6K Dec  2 00:04 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-x---   4 kevin  staff   136B Mar 22  2012 include
-rw-r--r--@  1 kevin  staff   2.0K Dec  1 23:56 package.xml
drwxr-x---@  6 kevin  staff   204B Dec  2 00:09 src
drwxr-x---   3 kevin  staff   102B Feb 26  2012 srv
```

Now running catkin_make inside of my serial_node package will create a build and devel directory with a bunch of files inside. However, no binaries are produced and I don't think anything is getting done with my service message.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49555/%5Bgroovy-beta%5D-troubles-migrating-to-catkin/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2012-12-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kevin, does this clear up any of the confusion?
http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/what#How_To_Use_Catkin_Packages

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-03**:
Yes, it helps ... things are beginning to compile ... this is much different than I had thought. I was mainly reading the migration stuff ...

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-12-03**:
Yeah, this is a page where I've been trying to maintain a catkin brief for those who just want to skip all the design details. If you find anything in catkin or the official documentation confusing or counter-intuitive, please comment on it [here](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_make does not behave like rosmake. You have to go into your workspace folder (/Users/kevin/ros_sandbox) and run it from there. Also, delete the folder /Users/kevin/ros_sandbox/serial_node/build.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-03**:
I tried that, but it doesn't work. My source code is located at ~/ros_sandbox/serial_node/src ... my workspace should be at the serial_node level with build, devel, src all there. If this isn't correct I am confused. [This](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) also isn't clear.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-03**:
So, you are saying that my source files ( eg, some_file.cpp) is not stored in the package, but up a level? That makes no sense.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2012-12-05**:
Please see the above linked docs to clarify how a catkin workspace looks like and the terms for the different folders. The previous comment referred to the "src" folder of the workspace. Your package should be checked out in there. Then catkin_make is invoked in the root of the workspace.